# How to mirror the state from switch button with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm still a beginner with ReactJS and I need to mirror my switch button in my application.

My switch button change the language from my application, and I have the same button in the header and footer of my pages.

When I change the language from the site, the another button doesn't change at the same time, for example, if I click in my header component to change the language, the button in my footer stay the same way.

[image]

I put this example into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-mountain-qdror?file=/src/index.js)

Can you tell me how do I fix the buttons?

```js
import "./styles.scss";
import { I18nProvider } from "./providers/i18n";
import ToggleLanguage from "./components/ToggleLanguage/ToggleLanguage.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <I18nProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Example Header</h3>
        <ToggleLanguage />
        <div style={{ margin: "20px 0" }} />
        <h3>Example Footer</h3>
        <ToggleLanguage />
      </div>
    </I18nProvider>
  );
}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import "./ToggleLanguage.scss";

// providers
import { AppContext } from "../../providers/app";
import { saveToStorage } from "../../utils/localStorage";

const ToggleLanguage = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  const onToggleSiteLang = (siteLang) => () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setLang", siteLang });
    saveToStorage("siteLang", siteLang);
  };

  return (
    <div className="toggle-language">
      <label className="switch">
        <input
          onChange={() => onToggleSiteLang(state.siteLang)}
          className="switch-checkbox"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        <div className="switch-button" />
        <div className="switch-labels">
          <span>PT</span>
          <span>EN</span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleLanguage;
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help/tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just control your checkbox with your state. `checked={state.siteLang === 'en'}`

```js
import React from "react";
import "./ToggleLanguage.scss";

// providers
import { AppContext } from "../../providers/app";
import { saveToStorage } from "../../utils/localStorage";

const ToggleLanguage = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  const onToggleSiteLang = (siteLang) => () => {
    dispatch({ type: "setLang", siteLang });
    saveToStorage("siteLang", siteLang);
  };

  return (
    <div className="toggle-language">
      <label className="switch">
        <input
          onChange={() => onToggleSiteLang(state.siteLang)}
          className="switch-checkbox"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={state.siteLang === 'en'}
        />
        <div className="switch-button" />
        <div className="switch-labels">
          <span>PT</span>
          <span>EN</span>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToggleLanguage;
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Also, `onToggleSiteLang` is returning another function, so you just need to pass in input `onChange={onToggleSiteLang}` and passing in just `state.siteLang` will keep it to same value, you need to toggle the value `state.siteLang === "PT" ? "EN" : "PT"`